# Python - How to encrypt text files and send it over sockets using AES

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, encryption

I have managed to get a program running with (symmetric and assymetric encryption (for symmetric keys)).
Also sending texts is no problem but the only problem is files. I constantly get an error (of course) because the file size is to big to be send using aes once. Does anyone happen to know a neat little trick to solve this problem or has some tips? (The *full* code works and gives correct IV and ciphertext, just not all ciphertext because it is to big to decrypt)

Short source code(rest of source code is correct):

encryption stuff:

```
def encrypt(message):
    cipher = AES.new(sym_key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    used_iv = cipher.iv
    print("USED IV")
    print(used_iv)
    ciphermessage = cipher.encrypt(pad(message,
                                       AES.block_size))  # TAKE MAX OF 1008 CHARS PER TIME, OTHERWISE ERROR, IF THIS GETS FIXED ITS NOT SIMPLE ENOUGH
    print("ciphermes")
    print(ciphermessage)
    TOTAL_MESS = used_iv + b" " + ciphermessage
    # conn.send(TOTAL_MESS)
    return TOTAL_MESS
  
def decrypt():
    totalciphermessage1 = conn.recv(1024)
    used_iv = totalciphermessage1[:16]  # if block goes wrong is is because of this probs
    totalciphermessage = totalciphermessage1[17:]
    print("CIPHER")
    cipher = AES.new(sym_key, AES.MODE_CBC, used_iv)
    print("CREATED CIPHER KEY, ")
    decoded_mess = unpad(cipher.decrypt(totalciphermessage), AES.block_size)
    print("UNPADDING")
    decoded_mess = decoded_mess.decode()
    print(decoded_mess)
    message = decoded_mess
    return message
```

server:

```
if cmd_com == "tasklist" or cmd_com == "TASKLIST":
            file = open("tasklist.txt", 'wb')
            print("RECEIVING DATA")
            image_chunk = socket_server.recv(4096)
            while 1:
                if image_chunk == b"%DONE%":
                    break
                elif len(image_chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    image_chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(image_chunk) % 16)
                file.write(decrypt_txt(image_chunk))
                image_chunk = socket_server.recv(4096)
            file.close()
            #PRINT OUT TASKLIST.TXT FILE FOR MASTER
            file1 = open("tasklist.txt", "r")
            while True:
                line = file1.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                print(line.strip())
            file1.close()
            os.remove("tasklist.txt")
```

client:

```
if instruction == 'tasklist' or instruction == "TASKLIST":
        returned_output = subprocess.check_output(
            instruction)  # first instruction was cmd_command without else statement shell
        print("TRYING TO ENCRYPT FILE")

    with open('cmd_output.txt', 'wb') as f:
        #f.write(encrypt(returned_output)) 
        #f.write(returned_output)
    f.close()
    print("DONE ENCRYPTING FILE")
    ##SEND TXT FILE AND DELETE IT AFTER
    path = 'cmd_output.txt'
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        image_data = file.read(4096)
        while image_data:
            conn.send(image_data)
            image_data = file.read(4096)
        file.close()
    time.sleep(1)  
    conn.send(b"%DONE%")
    print("DONE ENCRYPINTG")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    os.remove('cmd_output.txt')
```

Comment: Is this over TCP? You can't just send arbitrary blocks of data and expect the receiver to read arbitrary blocks and know what to do with them. At the very least, each message/chunk needs to specify how large they actually are, so the receiver knows how many bytes to read and when to stop reading.

Comment: Oeh, lang geleden dat ik augurken plukte :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes this is over TCP. This method does work with normal files. Unfortunately not with encrypted files (because of the decoding block limit). So what you are saying is that I need to split up my encrypted message and send it in blocks and receive it in blocks and decrypt it in blocks? Doesn't this mess with the encryption because now your decrypting parts of the ciphertext and not as a whole.

Comment: @Augurkenplukker12 "*this method does work with normal files*" - no, it doesn't. The logic you have is very wrong, terminating a file with `%DONE%` with no guarantee it is received that way. Had you designed your protocol correctly, the content being sent would not matter. As for the encryption, it is using a fixed block size, so just make sure you are decrypting whole blocks, yes. You can send and receive multiple blocks, just make sure you pay attention to block boundaries. You don't need every block up front to decrypt the whole message in one go,you can decrypt it in pieces.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Im just a noob and found it on a tutorial and it worked [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjkkJVMewTo). How would you send it(just normal files no encryption) I am very curious how you would do that because I searched everywhere online but the only thing that worked very well was that method. Btw I got it fixed with encryption and decryption of the large file but I'm still curious what the better way is to send files over wihtout using **%DONE%**

Comment: @Augurkenplukker12 "*how you would do that ... without using `%DONE%`*" - I would send the file size as a fixed length integer (32bit or 64bit, depending on needs) before sending the file bytes. The receiver can then read the integer first, then read the specified number of bytes. In the case of encryption, the integer can be the encrypted size, and then decrypt after each multiple of the block size is received (or, just save the entire encrypted file as-is first, then decrypt the file after the transfer)

Comment: when you send data over tcp, then you can use SSL and it will take care of the envryption and integrity